# Passing an if condition as function argument - Error unused arguments

Tags: r

I do not understand how to avoid the error "unused arguments" when I define functions like the one below.

I use RStudio Version 1.2.1335.

```r
condition = function(cond)
{
  ifelse (cond == 0, value = 1, value = -1)

  return(value)
}
```

When I try to run the function, e.g. condition(0), I get the following error message:

> Error in ifelse(cond == 0, value = 1, value = -1) : 
>     unused arguments (value = 1, value = -1)

How can I resolve this error?

Comment: Inside the `ifelse` remove the `value = `  You may need `condition <- function(cond) ifelse(cond == 0, 1, -1)`

Comment: FYI, in order to have a function return something, you need to have that 'something', in your case `value`, defined inside the function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `ifelse` usage is

> ifelse(test, yes, no)

Here, the 'yes' and 'no' doesn't need any assignment inside.  If there is any assignment, it should be outside the `ifelse` function

```
value <- ifelse(cond == 0, 1, -1)
```

---

In the OP's function, it doesn't need any assignment as well and then `return` statement as we can provide a single statement

```
condition <- function(cond) ifelse(cond == 0, 1, -1)
```

---

Also, the `ifelse` can be replaced with arithmetic way to replace the values

```
condition <- function(cond) c(-1, 1)[(!cond) + 1]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you go:

```
condition = function(cond)
{
  ifelse (cond == 0, value <- 1, value <- -1)

  return(value)
}
```

Test :

> ```
> > condition(0)
> [1] 1
> > condition(1)
> [1] -1
> ```

You can assign the values to `value` using the `<-` operator. Otherwise, `R`thinks you are passing an argument to `ifelse` and you'll get an error since there is no `value`argument to `ifelse`:

> ```
> > args(ifelse)
> function (test, yes, no) 
> NULL
> ```

**Edit**

Be careful, I wouldn't recommend you do it this way unless you understand how and why it works. The safest solution is to use `ifelse` properly, as pointed by [akrun](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3732271/akrun).

Comment: I did not think `ifelse` would work like that...or at least I 've never seen it written this way :)

Comment: Really, why? I wouldn't recommend it, that's for sure. It does what the OP intended though ...